# HTML form with different page redirection depending on input

Tags: html, forms, box

I want to have a box in HTML such as this one:

[image]

Particular thing, I need to do this using only HTML (no PHP or particular langage requiring server, or particular installation).

The reason for this is that it is meant to be used for HTML pages that will be opened from a USB key, not a website, and it has to be usable by any non-expert person. So no web-server configuration or installation required, such as what would be required for PHP, if I am right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about not using a Form, but just using a Javascript function.

I'm not sure if this probably is not possible due to security reasons, but it could be a solution...

```js
function redirect() {
  var input = document.getElementById("stuff");
  window.location = input.value;
}
```

```html
<span>NOM:</span>
<input type="text" id="stuff"></input>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="redirect()" value="Submit"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I needed thanks to Anders Anderson's answer. Here is the code for those interested in doing similar thing. First, for the Javascript

```
function redirect() {
  var answergiven = document.getElementById("answergiven");
  var realanswer = document.getElementById("realanswer");
  var nextpage = document.getElementById("nextpage");

  if(answergiven.value.toLowerCase() == realanswer.value.toLowerCase()){
      window.location = nextpage.value;
  }
  else{
      alert('Wrong answer, please try again.');
  }

  return false; // prevent further bubbling of event
}
```

And for the HTML part, there are two hidden variables that determine the real answer, and the next page to go to, and the text field for the answer

```
    <form name="myform" onSubmit="return redirect()">
    <span>Réponse:</span>
    <input type="text" id="answergiven" />
    <input name="tosubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="hidden" id="realanswer" value="theanswer" />
    <input type="hidden" id="nextpage" value="thenextpage.html" />
    </form>
```